# Postman testing Spring Boot REST API Protected by OAuth2 Client Sign in with Google

Tags: postman, google-oauth

I am working on a Spring Boot REST API protected by Sign-In With Google (OAuth2 Client).

In order to get a response from the API, I must be signed in. Signing in involves being redirected to Google's OAuth2 Client Sign-In page for the application.

Using Postman, how would I authenticate and get a response from the API? Currently, when I try to hit any endpoint using Postman I get a 200 OK response containing HTML of the Google Sign-In page, with no interactivity in the Postman response viewport.

I have tried capturing cookies using Postman interceptor but can't seem to figure out how to include the required auth cookie in the request.

Comment: Seems like some issue in the OAuth setup in postman. If everything is setup correctly it should redirect you to sign on page.

Comment: As a workaround, I am using "local" and "production" profiles in Spring Boot, each with its own SecurityConfig class. I'll leave this question open in case anybody has a better suggestion or if anybody wants to use my workaround. Example available on GitHub at https://github.com/io-jonathanlee/sparrow-express-api/blob/main/src/main/java/io/jonathanlee/sparrowexpressapi/config/SecurityProductionConfig.java